Training by consecutive three days to predict day4
I have the following task to do: Training by the consecutive 3 days to predict the each 4th day. Each day data represents one CSV file which has dimension 24x25. Every datapoints of each CSV file are pixels.
Now, I need to do that, predict day4(means 4th day) by using training data day1, day2, day3(means three consecutive days), after then calculate mse between predicted day4 data and original day4 data. Let's call it mse1.
Similarly, I need to predict the day5 (means 5th day) by using training data day2, day3, day4, and then calculate the mse2(mse between predicted day5 data and original day5 data)
I need to predict day6(means 6th day)by using training data day3, day4, day5,  and then calculate mse3(mse between predicted day6 data and original day6)
..........
And finally I want to Predict day93 by using training data day90, day91, day92,calculate mse90(mse between predicted day93 data and original day93)
I want to use Ridge regression, Linear regression and LSTM model. And we have 90 mse for each model.
My try:
for i in range(3, min(93, len(data_flattened_scaled))):
    # Select the last 3 days as input and the next day as the target
    X_train = data_flattened_scaled[i-3:i].reshape(1, -1)
    print("X-train")
    print(list(range(i-3, i)))
   
    y_train = data_flattened_scaled[i].reshape(1, -1)
    print("y-train")
    print(i)
   
    # Linear Regression
    lr_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred_lr = lr_model.predict(X_train)
    mse_lr.append(mean_squared_error(y_train, y_pred_lr))

    # Ridge Regression
    ridge_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred_ridge = ridge_model.predict(X_train)
    mse_ridge.append(mean_squared_error(y_train, y_pred_ridge))

    # LSTM
    X_train_lstm = data_flattened_scaled[i-3:i].reshape(1, 3, 600)
    lstm_model.fit(X_train_lstm, y_train.reshape(1, 600), epochs=30, verbose=0, callbacks=[early_stopping])
    y_pred_lstm = lstm_model.predict(X_train_lstm)
    mse_lstm.append(mean_squared_error(y_train.reshape(600,), y_pred_lstm[0]))

But teacher saying, I did wrong for every model. I see that all the mse for regression model is close to 0, I'm still surprised at how well linear regression is doing.  The lstm method gives a big peak, I would expect linear regression to make a large mistake.
Would anybody give me any correct algorithms for every model?
My data sample for example the day10 is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ha0DMbg8hyxP0AHv6WXanzLfRsNupOfU/view?usp=drive_link
One thing note that before asking here, I asked in stack overflow they suggest me to ask here.

One place where you have gone awry is that you don't really have a mean squared error at an individual day. You have one error (more accurately called a residual): the difference between the true and predicted values. The mean squared error would be the mean of those squared differences, and you get one per model.
I do not think the loop should be needed. For the ridge and linear regressions, your data would be three feature columns denoting the previous three days and then one outcome column containing the value on the fourth day. For instance, if the time series is $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$, you would have five rows.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & y\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The first three columns are your features, and the last is the outcome. Then you regress the outcome one the three features, same as usual. Those features happen to come from earlier in the time series, and perhaps the sequential nature of the data should be given more attention, such as with an explicit time series model (e.g., ARIMA) or a neural network architecture that is designed for sequential data (e.g., LSTM).

@S.M. Questions about the code are off-topic here but may be on-topic on Stack Overflow. If you want clarification on the statistics, I am happy to help.

One question, when I use lstm, I get the spike the though out 90 days. Which is correct, But when I use regression(ridge, linear) models I always get mse 0, throughout the 90 days. Why is it happening? We can't use Ridge and Linear Regression, they don't capture temporal  dependencies effectively and lacks the capabilities to model sequential Patters in data, thus making it unsuitable for time-series predictions like involving daily patterns. So even if we use these models we only get MSE 0 always. Beside this LSTM models are specifically designed for  Sequential data. Am I correct?

If you have additional questions, please post them as distinct questions rather than letting questions and answers get buried in the comments. @S.M.
